# Is there any bus that works all day-long between Tirana International Airport and Skanderbeg Square?

Tags: public-transport, buses, albania, tirana

I have a flight from Istanbul to Tirana at 3 Dec, 21:40 and my return flight is at 6 Dec, 02:35 local times. My airbnb home is so close to [Skanderbeg Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skanderbeg_Square) and I'm looking for a public transportation on these hours between these places other than taxi.

[Based on this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_lines_in_Tirana), there is "one" line serving [Tirana International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tirana_International_Airport_N%C3%ABn%C3%AB_Tereza) from and to Skanderbeg Square called Rinas Express. ("Rinas" is the place (or a close place) name where airport locates as far as I understand)

The below images shows the working hours for that bus line but it's between 07:00-18:00 so I *can't* use it since it doesn't catch my flight schedule.

[image]

I also checked [this Bus article from airport website](http://www.tirana-airport.com/l/4/16/getting-here-parking/bus/), and it says;

> LU-NA shpk offers a shuttle service from TIA to Tirana and vice versa.
>   The bus is stationed behind the National Theatre of Opera and Ballet (which is close to my airbnb home).
>   The rate for a single fare is 250 Albanian Lek (From May 1-st, price
>   of the ticket will be 300 Albanian Lek).
>
> Service Hours:
>
> Tiranë - TIA: every one hour starting from 07:00 until 23:00
>
> TIA - Tiranë:  every one hour starting from 08:00 until 24:00

but I *couldn't* be sure this service is *still* available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This website](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Tirana-Airport-TIA/Skanderbeg-Square) provides several transportation options for your outbound trip and a shuttle for the return journey:

## Bus

33 minutes, £2. This takes 30 minutes and it takes you Tirana which is a 3 minutes walk from the square. **The last bus is at 23:00 and the first one at 08:00**, which works for your inbound flight but not your outbound one:

[image]

## Shuttle

There is a shuttle for £3, with the last one arrivant at 0:30. I assume this will be enough time for you (2 hours before your flight):

[image]